# Can't mount usb key filesystem

Tags: linux, debian, usb-flash-drive, mount, automount

8GB FAT32 filesystem that normally mounted as intended using usbmount. When I went to take it out to plug into a difference computer I did umount /dev/sda1 which is where it was.

Now it fails to automount either on boot or when I plug it in. When I run

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/sda1 /media/
```

it fails to mount with dmesg

```
[   15.204564] FAT-fs (sda1): bogus number of reserved sectors
[   15.214057] FAT-fs (sda1): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
```

I presume I shouldn't have umounted then? How do I restore mounting (and automounting) of the drive? OS is Raspbian (Debian) on a RaspberryPi

Comment: It's corrupted. `Can't find a valid FAT filesystem`

Comment: So it was. How would that have happened? It was working fine when I removed it correctly from my W7 workstation?

Comment: Have you tried running fsck on it?  And does it work if you plug it into a Windows system?